# Ruby on Rails edit form to show first_name and last_name from the helpers

Tags: string, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, input, split

I'm a beginner in Rails. I have a User model and it has a field called name. The name of the user will be inputted by joining the first_name and last_name (name = "#{first_name} #{last_name}" values that I'm getting from the input form. But when I try to edit the user I'm splitting the value of the name from the db and show it in the view.(name.split(' ').first for first_name and name.split(' ').last for last_name from the users_helper. But the problem here is if the value of first_name is Veronica Roth and the last_name is Taylor the values that is showing are Veronica for first_name and Taylor for last_name in the view. Is there any efficient way to show the first_name and last_name in the edit form as it the actual first_name and last_name without adding first_name and last_name columns to DB(name is already in DB).

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_paranoid
  validates :email, format: { with: Devise.email_regexp }

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

end
```

**users_helper.rb**

```
module UsersHelper
  def get_form_value(form_name, user)
    form_value = ''
    case form_name
    when "first_name"
      if user.present? and user.name.present?
        form_value = user.name.split(" ").first
      end
    when "last_name"
      if user.present? and user.name.present?
        form_value = user.name.split(" ").last
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to consider all elements but the last element in the name array (the one generated from using split over the name attribute) as the `first_name` and the `last_name` to always have the value of the last element in your name array.

If that's the case, you can simply do:

```
*first_name, last_name = user.name.split(' ')
first_name = first_name.join(' ')
```

What we are doing here is simply destructuring our name array into two variables, `first_name` and `last_name`, the `*` operator before the `first_name` keyword is called the splat operator. In this case, it's taking every element except the last one and collecting them into one array, we then join that array into a string using the `join` method.

You can read more about destructing here: https://jsarbada.wordpress.com/2019/02/05/destructuring-with-ruby/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any any way to get the actual values for first_name and last_name? For ex: first_name: "Mary Elizabeth" and last_name: "Anne Winstead".  The above piece of will return "Mary Elizabeth Anne" as first_name and "Winstead" as last_name.